# Elm install always fails with "ConnectionTimeout" error (in WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, elm, connection-timeout

I'm new to Elm. and I'm not good at English. So, if any ambiguous or wrong thing is there, please let me correct it.

----------- **edit** -----------
All my problem below is on WSL. when I'm trying on windows, all work fine. then... why `elm install` doesn't work on WSL? did you have any idea?

-------- **problem** --------
when I try to `elm-test init`, it doesn't work like below

```
$ elm-test init
Here is my plan:
  
  Add:
    elm/random               1.0.0
    elm-explorations/test    1.2.2

Would you like me to update your elm.json accordingly? [Y/n]: 
-- PROBLEM DOWNLOADING PACKAGE -------------------------------------------------

I was trying to download the source code for elm/random 1.0.0, so I tried to
fetch:

    https://github.com/elm/random/zipball/1.0.0/

But my HTTP library is giving me the following error message:

    ConnectionTimeout

Are you somewhere with a slow internet connection? Or no internet? Does the link
I am trying to fetch work in your browser? Maybe the site is down? Does your
internet connection have a firewall that blocks certain domains? It is usually
something like that!
```

but my Browser(Chrome) is working beautifully, and even in WSL (the environment that I run `elm-test init` command at) is too.

```
$ curl https://github.com/elm/random/zipball/1.0.0/
https://codeload.github.com/elm/random/legacy.zip/1.0.0<body>You are being <a href="https://codeload.github.com/elm/random/legacy.zip/1.0.0">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

then I also try again to redirect the URL

```
$ curl https://codeload.github.com/elm/random/legacy.zip
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

I think there's no Network Problem. My PC can connect with the repo, and I think it will be downloaded well.

I lastly tried just `elm install`, and that throws the same error too. it seems like Elm can't connect with the repo, even if My PC can.

```
$ elm install elm/random
Here is my plan:
  
  Add:
    elm/random    1.0.0

Would you like me to update your elm.json accordingly? [Y/n]: 

-- PROBLEM DOWNLOADING PACKAGE -------------------------------------------------

I was trying to download the source code for elm/random 1.0.0, so I tried to
fetch:

    https://github.com/elm/random/zipball/1.0.0/

But my HTTP library is giving me the following error message:

    ConnectionTimeout

Are you somewhere with a slow internet connection? Or no internet? Does the link
I am trying to fetch work in your browser? Maybe the site is down? Does your
internet connection have a firewall that blocks certain domains? It is usually
something like that!
```

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: I've been using Elm on WSL2 for a over a year now without issue. Are you still on WSL1 by chance? That could be the source of the issue. Does `elm install elm/random` work when not being done through `elm-test install`? It's possible it's an issue with `elm-test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had reason to use WSL for elm development. It wasn't much fun and I'm glad to be back on Mac! What I found was that certain disk operations on WSL seemed to go very slowly and that could lead a variety of weird issues.

I was using Webstorm, which does not handle WSL well, so in the end I did everything on C: drive (rather than in `/home/...`) so that webstorm could run the windows version of elm-format, while my node development environment was run on the linux layer.

That's not a precise answer to your question but just to say that it can be done, but its not an ideal way to write Elm code in my experience

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and it was solved.
It was due to DNS server settings.

1. Create a file `/etc/resolv.conf` and write the following line.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then WSL will refer to Google Public DNS and works fine.
However, when restart WSL, the settings revert back.
Therefore, the following settings are also required.

2. Create a file `/etc/wsl.conf` and write the following line.

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

3. `wsl --shutdown` and restart WSL.

Reference link
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-522201021